# Python Typing: Automatically set generic type based on method implementation in subclass?

Tags: python, types, abstract-class, python-typing

I want to drive the type of a generic based on the implementation in a subclass automatically.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, List
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
T = TypeVar("T")

class AbstractClass(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def get_list(self) -> List[T]:
        return [self.value()]

    @abstractmethod
    def value(self) -> T:
        pass

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
    def value(self) -> int:
        return 1

instance = ConcreteClass()
value = instance.get_list() # I want this to automatically be List[int]
```

Technically I could implement this with `class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass[int]):`
But then I'd need to type hint every subclass twice.

Is it possible to automatically drive the generic type by the implementation of a method in a subclass?

Comment: What do you mean? `class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass[int]):` is great...

Comment: I work in VFX with people who only code some of the time on top of their artist jobs. Many of them don't fully understand typing, and placing the type hint in the class definition seems unintuitive (and they may not do it when implementing subclasses.)

I was hoping for a way to automatically drive the type hint by the return type of the subclass method, so it would be easier to understand. But if this isn't possible, I understand!

Comment: Isn't possible afaik